# Component based design

Tags: components

Lets say you make a game engine, and you have several `GameObjects` and every `GameObject` have a list of components that you can add or remove.

Lets say there is a `MeshComponent` who has vertices, normals etc. If several `GameObjects` have the same `MeshComponent`, there will be a lot of memory waste. Of course there are many ways to implements this but I want some good advice how to solve this? How do components share data that is not going to be modified?

Comment: Static classes? Does your language support those?

Comment: The language is C++ so its supported, but is it the best way to implement? Then you have to do a mesh component for every different mesh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ does not have static classes.

If several `GameObjects` have the same `MeshComponent`, there will be **NO** memory waste.
Because, of course, it is the same `MeshComponent`...

You will waste memory if you have many copies of the `MeshComponent` which conceptually should be identical.

If many `GameObjects` need to refer to the same `MeshComponent` then they should each hold a (smart) pointer to the same `MeshComponent`.